# Unity build shows wrong date

Tags: unity, c#, build-process

[image]

I made a 3D game in Unity named Sniper Shot.

I am facing a problem when I build the project: at the end it shows the wrong date of build.

I have tried many scripts resolving this issue but I did not find any accurate way to fix it.

I completed this project on 4 march 2019 but this is showing me a wrong date, 23 July 2017.

Comment: Can you confirm your current system date & time settings?

Comment: my system date and time is alright